# Capturing Return Value of stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-4.0, roleprovider

im trying to implement Custom Role provider for my .Net application. Im trying to check if the role added by user already exists in the db or not by using the Asp.NET's role provider stored procedure like

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("aspnet_Roles_RoleExists", sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@RoleName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = "/";
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = roleName;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int,4).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
try
{
  sqlConnection.Open();
  sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  int x = (int)sqlCommand.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value;
  if ((int)sqlCommand.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value == 0)
                 ...
```

the problem is that when i add the role e.g  `admin` and run the sp manually from the database like

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[aspnet_Roles_RoleExists]
        @ApplicationName = N'/',
        @RoleName = N'admin'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

it gives me the correct result but from the application if i try to add the role `admin` again the statement

```
(int)sqlCommand.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value
```

always give me `0`.  Can anybody guide me to what is causing this behavior

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412256/return-value-using-sqlcommand

Comment: @SebastianMeine but im not using any class of the sort as `SafeDataReader`

Comment: You have a point there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more likely because you inverted the values expected by the stored procedure:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@RoleName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = "/";
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = roleName;
```

And it should be:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@RoleName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = roleName;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = "/";
```

You were passing roleName as parameter for the ApplicationName.

Comment: i dont have words to express my gratitude ... god bless you @lcarus